# How does Report Portal take screenshots of failed testcases in the case of TestNG framework?

Tags: testng, reportportal

Does Report Portal use WebDriver to take the screenshot of failed testcases?
I did not see the usage of WebDriver in the source code of the java-testNG listener agent.
May i know how this is done?
Or RP does not have the capability of capturing the screenshot for TestNG based frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

ReportPortal does not take your screenshot, you need to implement the code from web driver to take the screenshot and then send it to ReportalPortal by using your logger (log4j2/log4j/logback).

for example (from local browser-chrome)

```
 Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot(this);
 
 LOGGER.debug("RP_MESSAGE#FILE#{}#{}", screenshot.takeScreenShot(imageName,true), "snapshot");
```